# popup window with particular browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popupwindow

When I click any button in opera brower, it should offer a popup  window in IE browser. IE is already installed in target machine.

my code is below:

```
var popup;
function FingerPrint() {
    popup = window.open("fingerprint.html", "Popup", "width=300,height=300");
    popup.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Presently, this is opening in the same Opera browser; whereas I want it to open in IE.

I am using this for asp.net, javascript

Please help with relevant code/guidance. Newbie here! Please be kind. Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done!

The browser that renders the page is the one that will always open a new window (or tab). You don't have the option to set a different browser in `window.open` options.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible since JS is not allowed to run local files. (Which IE is)